# Project still searching for new version of library, while I'm using old version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, shared-libraries, package

I was using NuGet console package installer to install libraries in my Visual Studio. Now I found out that some functions doesn't work with a new library named Accord.Math v3.2.0. I'm now using the old .DLL's v3.0.2 but Visual Studio gives following error while starting up a project

Error:
Cannot find file assembly Accord.Math, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fa1a88e29555ccf7 or not able to load one of the dependencies. The manifestdefinition from the founded assembly is not confirm the assembly-reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Stacktrace

```
bij CSharpLib.Class1.CreateITKImageDouble(Double[,] matrix, UInt16 row, UInt16 column)
bij TotalDoppen.FormMain.FormMain_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Project\FormMain.vb:regel 36
bij System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
bij System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
bij System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, found it. Deleting the Accord.Math 3.2.0 reference in App.Config did the trick.